# What does the "impedance" value of audio transformers specifically mean in terms of inductance?

Tags: transformer, audio, impedance, inductance

So I've searched the web, looked into other questions here (e.g. [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239656/what-does-600-600-%CE%A9-mean-for-an-audio-transformer)), but I am not really any wiser.

What does the impedance of a transformer specifically mean? I.e. **how can I deduce the component values, such as inductance**, DCR, capacitance (if at all).

I know that the ratio of the given "impedances" corresponds to impedance *conversion ratio* (i.e. square or turns ratio). But how do I get the *absolute* impedance over frequency for primary and secondary? Is there some undisclosed default frequency at which these impedances apply?

[Example 1](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/410/MET_09_T-1892737.pdf): A 10 kΩ : 10 kΩ transformer, which has 1 kΩ DCR primary and 1.3 kΩ DCR secondary. **What are the inductances?**

[Example 2](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/410/SP_67-1892915.pdf): A 600 Ω : 600 Ω transformer, which has 72 Ω DCR primary and 92 Ω DCR secondary. **What are the inductances?**

Comment: Probably impedance @ 1 kHz.

Comment: If you terminate one side in the labeled impedance, you get the labeled impedance on the other side (over the working frequency range). If you don't, you get *something else*, which they don't feel obligated to specify.

Comment: @hobbs this is helpful. That means that inductance has to be at least a certain value so that the input impedance does not drop below the specced value at the lower end of the operation frequency range. So say for a 20 Hz - 20 kHz specced 10K:10K transformer, the magnetizing inductance would be such that it is at least 10k at 20 Hz (being in parallel with the 10k load resistance), so creating a -3dB point at 20 Hz.. Something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What are the inductances?*

I'm not saying this answer is 100% accurate nor, am I saying that it is wise to make estimations like these without doing a physical test but, it probably boils down to the frequency response stated in the data sheet (600 Ω transformer): -

[image]

So, with a 600 Ω load on the output and, a 600 Ω source feeding the primary, if the input frequency drops from some nominal mid-range value down to 300 Hz, the output amplitude will likely reduce by 2 dB. This is sufficient information to estimate the primary magnetization inductance.

In other words, the magnetization inductance is now starting to have an influence. At mid-range frequencies it can be ignored but, like any transformer, it's a safe bet that at some "low-ish" frequency, the magnetization inductance will start to mess things up.

Just for the sake of making the numbers simple, lets say the magnetization inductance caused the output voltage to droop by 3 dB at 300 Hz. This would be the same as adding "an inductor" in parallel with a 600 Ω resistor when both are fed from a 600 Ω source and, seeing the voltage reduce by 3 dB. I chose 3 dB because I know that the inductive reactance would be 300 Ω at 300 Hz (matching the Thevenin resistance of 300 Ω).

Turn this into inductance and you get 159 mH. Sanity check using micro-cap: -

[image]

At 300 Hz (left marker), the response is 3.01 dB down on the response at 10 kHz (right marker).

Comment: Yes I think this is enough information to find the primary (and thus secondary) inductance. And one probably can use the leakage inductance and winding capacitance to make a similar argument about the higher frequency -3dB point! Thanks

Comment: Based on the data sheet, it will be trickier to make the calculations at 100 kHz and, it will be less reliable. It pi55es me off that audio transformer manufacturer's are so poor at giving full or decent specs.

Comment: I just also made a simulation. The higher cutoff is probably given by the leakage inductance (coupling coefficient) alone, and the resulting LR lowpass. If I instead assumed perfect coupling (zero leakage inductance), I would need nonsensical values of winding capacitance to force a 100 kHz RC lowpass - in the nF range.

Comment: Yes I agree; it has to be leakage inductance because the 600 ohm source impedance is waaaay too low to deliver a credible C value at 100 kHz.

Comment: This is the correct way to design a signal transformer for some impedance and attenuation, and should be close to the actual value -- of course a given part could always have more, but it can't have less than this inductance without violating its spec. Beware however, this does not account for saturation -- for that, one also needs allowed signal level at minimum frequency.

Comment: (For example, 50mW into 600Ω is about 5.5Vrms sine; if this figure is determined by saturation at LF, that implies a limit at ~300Hz.  Saturation is inversely proportional to frequency: potentially, it could handle 11V at 600Hz, etc., but the small-signal frequency limits will still be as above.)

Comment: @TimWilliams please leave your comments as a formal answer if you believe them to be relevant to the question.

Comment: @Andyaka Writing a formal answer doesn't feel necessary, as this one contains most of the information it would contain; rewriting this part seems unnecessary. (Should I simply copy it whole..?)