How do you choose an audio isolation transformer for a microphone?
I found a few SE Q/A's for audio transformer characterization, but they neither address calculating the impedance match, nor consider signal loss for weak audio sources (like those from a microphone).
I would like to understand how to choose a transformer component with a 600:600-ohm match to convert a balanced microphone output to an unbalanced microphone input:

[ image source ]
Question: If I the information below from a datasheet, how can I use the that to estimate the following characteristics?

low frequency cut-off as Hz approaches DC (ie, can it pass 20Hz audio? 40 Hz?)
insertion loss
input/output impedance

Note that I am not attached to any particular transformer, this is just an example for the purpose of discussion (and it was in stock at a PCB manufacturer):
 datasheet

The question link below might help you to relate impedance, inductance and freq. response specs. Unfortunately, audio transformer manufacturers rarely give a full set of specs, so you have to fill in the blank spots via calculation/simulators: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/648953/237061 If you are given the inductance spec, that is already very very good

The transformer that you linked to is not an audio transformer.
There are transformers designed specifically for use with microphones. Their datasheets should give you the information you need, often including a frequency response graph. Note that a transformer good down to 20 Hz is likely to be relatively large, and priced accordingly. Small ones, say an inch square, are generally specced at something like a 200 to 4000 Hz response.

Additionally, if having to supply power wouldn't be a problem, a differential amplifier may be able to provide better performance at lower cost than a transformer-based solution when isolation isn't required, and even when isolation is required a device that amplitude-modulates a high-frequency signal with the audio, passes it through a small (and cheap) high-frequency transformer, and then demodulates the result may be cheaper than an audio-frequency transformer.

Do a search for something like 'microphone transformer data' (without the quotes).  A problem is that many of the products are decades old and no longer available.  But going through the catalogs and datasheets will help you get a feel for what to look for.
Beyer was (is?) one of the big dogs in this area.
https://www.technicalaudio.com/pdf/Beyer_Dynamic/Beyer_Dynamic_input_transformers_1976_oct_cat.pdf
